# Is it possible change millisInFuture without recreate CountDownTimer?

Tags: android

Here my code that uses the `CountDownTimer` class:

```
   private void initCountDownTimer() {
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, COUNT_DOWN_INTERVALE_MS) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                getView().setCountDownTimerValue(millisUntilFinished);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                getView().setCountDownTimerValue(0);
            }
        };
    }
```

It works fine.

But the question is: Is it possible change `millisInFuture` without recreate new object `CountDownTimer`?

Comment: Not sure if I'm getting your question because of the small amount of code you provide but it sure appears so since it's a class member

Comment: Yes,  countDownTimer is a class member

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to change `millisInFuture`, without re-initializing the `CountDownTimer` using the constructor, since it is not an exposed variable. You can `cancel()` the timer and start a new one